# Thread memory changes while suspended

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I suspended a thread in another process using `SuspendThread` and then I get its context using GetThreadContext. GetThreadContext succeeds.
Then I read parts of its stack with `ReadProcessMemory`.
I do some stuff (still when the thread is suspended) and then I read the same memory again.
I assumed that while the thread is suspended, its memory should stay the same but I get different results in the memory readings.

What could cause this and how can I make the memory remain the same?

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the stack of the suspended thread, and nothing else, and not the stack of another thread ? - also, if some of that stack was handed to another thread (with a pointer), other threads can access and modify the memory of your suspended thread.

Comment: The target process has only one thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *What could cause this?* Many things *could* cause this but the *likely* (p = .999999) cause is that some buggy code of yours is polluting the thread's memory by writing into it.
2. *and how can I make the memory remain the same?* There's only one answer here: fix the bug in your code.

Comment: But I'm not writing anything into that process memory.

Comment: Not on purpose, perhaps. But *somebody's* writing into it. And that somebody can only be you. That's the bug.

Comment: but the only way I can write to that process memory is by using "WriteProcessMemory" and I don't.

Comment: Then this deserves another question, something like: how can I debug a thread that seems to have its memory changed randomly?

Comment: Does the thread do anything 'interesting' before it is suspended?  Submit any OS callbacks, for example?

Comment: @Idov Any other thread can write to the stack of any other thread within a process. It does not require WriteProcessMemory to do so.

Comment: oops.. my bad. I was changing the pointer to the memory I just read. Thanks :)